# np.trapz calculation in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I used the `np.trapz` to calculate the area under a time series and the value appears to be different from what I get from manual calculation.

`np.trapz` calculation looks something like this:

```
time_list, value_list = zip(*sorted(zip(time_list, value_list )))
area = np.trapz(value_list , dx= np.diff(time_list))
duration = (max(time_list) - min(time_list)).total_seconds()

try:
    mean= area/duration 
except Exception:
    mean= 'no value'
```

where `value_list` and `time_list` are the values and the corresponding timestamps in the format of `datetime`. This gives `0 days 01:46:19.320000` for area.

Manual calculation:

```
a = (pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:59:29.960000') - pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:58:41.960000')).total_seconds()
b = (pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:59:31.960000') - pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:59:29.960000')).total_seconds()
c = (pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:59:34.120000') - pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:59:31.960000')).total_seconds()
d = (pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:59:36.120000') - pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:59:34.120000')).total_seconds()
e = (pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 04:01:12.680000') - pd.to_datetime('2001-01-04 03:59:36.120000')).total_seconds()

Area = (45.5+44)*e/2 + (44 + 43)*d/2 + (43 + 41.5)*c/2 + (41.5 + 38.5)*b + (38.5 + 36.5)*a/2

display(str(datetime.timedelta(seconds= Area)))

Area
```

This gives `6459.320000000001 seconds`, which equals `1:47:39.320000` for area.

I confirm that the inputs of `value_list` and `time_list` to `np.trapz` are the same as the manual calculation, but why are they different? Any contribution is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, the order is not correct. `np.trapz` computes:

```
(45.5+44)*a/2 + (44+43)*b/2 + ...
```

while your formula is

```
(45.5+44)*e/2 + (44+43)*d/2 + ...
```

Comment: Hi Quang, thank you for the answer. But I think the order seems correct, the plot shows that the value increases with time. Can there be other reasons?

Comment: Take my word :-). Change the order like I said and you would see the the results agree (I tested).

Comment: Yeah just reversed the order and return value is `6107.26 seconds, ie '1:41:47.260000'`